# how to make InfiniteScroll implementation updated because it update only one time in React table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-table

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react' ;

import { useTable , useSortBy } from 'react-table';

import MOCK_DATA from '../MOCK_DATA.json';

import { Columns } from './columns';

import {Checkbox} from './Checkbox';

import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';

export default function DefaultTable() {

const columns = useMemo(() => Columns , [])
const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA , [])
const [items , setItems] = useState(data);
const [hasMore , setHasMore] = useState(true)

const [offset, setOffset] = useState(10);


const fetchMoreData = () => {
  
    // a fake async api call like which sends
    // 20 more records in .5 secs
    if (items.length >= items.length +1) {
        setHasMore( false );
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        setOffset( offset + 10);
     
    }, 100);
 
  };



const {getTableProps , 
    getTableBodyProps , 
    headerGroups ,
     rows ,
      prepareRow,
      allColumns,
      getToggleHideAllColumnsProps
     } = useTable ({
        columns , 
        data
    },
    useSortBy
  )

return (

<div>
<div>
 
        <Checkbox {...getToggleHideAllColumnsProps()} /> Toggle All
        
    
    {
        allColumns.map(column =>(
            <span key={column.id}>
                <label>
                    <input type='checkbox' {...column.getToggleHiddenProps()} />
                    {column.Header}

                </label>
            </span>
        ))
    }
   </div>
     <div 
     id="scrollableDiv"
     style={{
       height: 320,
       overflow: 'auto',
       display: 'flex',
     }}
    >
    
   <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={rows.length} //This is important field to render the next data
        next={fetchMoreData}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}
        loader={<h4>Loading more items...</h4>}
        scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
        endMessage={
            <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
            </p>
        }
     
        >
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                    <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}
                        <span>
                            {column.isSorted
                            ? column.isSortedDesc
                                ? ' '
                                : ' '
                            : ''}
                        </span>
              </th>
                ))}
            </tr>
            ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.slice(0, offset).map((row) => {
        // {rows.map((row) => {
   
                prepareRow(row)
                return(
                    <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                        {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                            return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                        })}
                        
                    </tr>
                )
            })}
          
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </InfiniteScroll>

</div>
</div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i;m asking about why fetched data function didn't updating while scrolling , it works for one time and fetch second 10 but after that it doesn't work